# How to match and replace specified last letter(s) of words with a different letter in a sentence

Tags: java, regex, string

I read from a text file.

My sentence is: `tax mass plus match`

When I try that expression and code.

Actual output: `taes maeses plues mateses`

Expected output: `taxes masses pluses matches`

```
String line_2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt.txt")).get(0);
Pattern pattern_Plural = Pattern.compile("\\b*[(ss)(s)(sh)(ch)(s)(x)(z)]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m_Plural = pattern_Plural.matcher(line_2);

if (m_Plural.find()) {
   String str1 = m_Plural.replaceAll("es");
   System.out.println(str1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String line_2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt.txt")).get(0);
System.out.println(line_2.replaceAll("(?i)(ss|s|sh|ch|s|x|z)(\\b)", "$1es"));
```

`$1` represents the captured group helps to keep the `(ss|s|sh|ch|s|x|z)` part of the text.

`(?i)` is used for case insensitivity.

Output:

```
taxes masses pluses matches
```

Comment: I'm assuming the OP wants to turn singular words into plural. Note that your solution does not consider the endings. For example the word `message` is converted to `messesage` which makes no sense.

Comment: `\\b` is more convenient than negative lookahead `(?!\\B)`

Comment: @Toto oh yes :)

Comment: @METİN happy to help